# Remove the unnecessary padding inside the HTML Table Cells, which is being generated from Python script

Tags: python, html, css

I have a python script which dynamically generates a HTML Table according to some specifications provided to it.

A sample generated output is given below,

[image]

As you can see, it is possible that,

- It is possible for two consecutive cells to be merged (it is done from the Python Script, again. With the help of Jinja2)
- It is also possible for one cell to be divided horizontally into two or more sections

^These two possibilities can occur at any position in the HTML table.

1. The main issue I am facing here is this that I am getting unnecessary spacing/padding in all my cells (which are not horizontally divided). I don't understand the cause behind it and I can't seem to resolve this issue either. Can anyone help me to identify what changes do I need to make to make it look more presentable (i.e., no unnecessary space above and below the text in all cells). For example, in the first cell, there's unnecessary padding added above the "Calculus and Analytical Geometry" and also below the "Dr. Mushtaq Ahmed" Text. However, in the same HTML table, if you look at the cell which is horizontally divided into two sections, this padding is not being added.
2. Similarly, I want to somehow align the "Name" and the "Room" in one Row. For example, for the first Cell, "Dr. Mushtaq Ahmed" and "Room #1" should be aligned in same row (rather than in two different rows). I have tried to make different changes to achieve this but they don't seem to work properly (One change did work for me, but it disrupted the shape of the Horizontally divided cell and hence, I didn't adopt it)

What I am actually looking to get is similar to this image,

[image]

The code for the HTML Table I shared above is as follows,

```css
:root {
  --border-strong: 3px solid #777;
  --border-normal: 1px solid gray;
}

body {
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

table>caption {
  font-size: 6mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 1mm;
}


/* 210 x 297 mm */

table {
  width: 297mm;
  height: 210mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: var(--border-normal);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.6mm;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

tbody tr> :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* top header */

.top_head>th {
  width: 54mm;
  height: 10mm;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-top: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.top_head :first-child {
  width: 27mm;
  border: var(--border-strong);
}

.top_head :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* left header */

tbody th {
  border-left: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody>tr:last-child th {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}


/* row */

tbody td>div {
  height: 34mm;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vertical_span_all {
  font-size: 5mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

.vertical_span_all div {
  height: 10mm;
}


/* td contents */


.note {
  font-size: 3mm;
}

.note :last-child {
  float: right;
}

@page {
  margin: 5mm;
}
.new-page {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
.center
{
  text-align: center;

}
.left
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 6px;
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
.right
{
    text-align: right;  margin-right: 4px;
}
.teacher
{
    margin-left: 4px;
}
td{
  height:175px;
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Heading -->
    <h1 class="center">CS-1D</h1>

<!-- Table -->
    <table border="1">

<!-- Day/Periods -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center" ><br>
                <b>Day/Period</b></br>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>I</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>II</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <b>III</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <b>1:15-1:45</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>IV</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>V</b>
            </td>

        </tr>
<!-- Monday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Monday</b></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Calculus and Analytical Geometry</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Calculus_and_Analytical_Geometry@Room_#1@Dr.Mushtaq_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>




                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>




                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #9</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Dr. Rabia Maqsood</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals@Room_#9@Dr._Rabia_Maqsood</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td rowspan="6" class="center">
                        <h2>L<br>U<br>N<br>C<br>H</h2>
                    </td>


                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Lab #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Muhammad Azeem Iftikhar</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals_-_Lab@Lab_#1@Muhammad_Azeem_Iftikhar</p>
                        <p class="right">2</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>






        </tr>
<!-- Tuesday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Tuesday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Rida Akram<hr>English Composition and Comprehension</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram<hr>English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#7@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --><p class="left"></p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #7</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Sadia Ashfaq</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram<hr>English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#7@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Rida Akram</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #3</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Farah Iqbal</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#3@Farah_Iqbal</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>


        </tr>
<!-- Wednesday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Wednesday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #7</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Zia Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Islamic_Studies/Ethics@Room_#7@Zia_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #6</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Sadia Ashfaq</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#6@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Applied Physics</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Waheed Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Applied_Physics@Room_#1@Waheed_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>


        </tr>
<!-- Thursday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Thursday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Calculus and Analytical Geometry</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #5</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Calculus_and_Analytical_Geometry@Room_#5@Dr.Mushtaq_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #10</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Dr. Rabia Maqsood</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals@Room_#10@Dr._Rabia_Maqsood</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #4</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Farah Iqbal</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#4@Farah_Iqbal</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Applied Physics</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Waheed Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Applied_Physics@Room_#1@Waheed_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



        </tr>
<!-- Friday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Friday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #6</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Zia Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Islamic_Studies/Ethics@Room_#6@Zia_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p class="left">Introduction to Information and Communication Technology - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Lab #4</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Aqsa Younas</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Introduction_to_Information_and_Communication_Technology_-_Lab@Lab_#4@Aqsa_Younas</p>
                        <p class="right">2</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>





                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #3</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Amna Farooq</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#3@Amna_Farooq</p>
                        <p class="right">2</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>





        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
<p class = "new-page"></div>


</html>
```

Here is the `template.html` code which is being used to generate the HTML Files. Multiple HTML files are being generated (for different sections) and then they are combined to make a PDF file. Therefore, **it is important that height of the table is maintained, so that every generated HTML file covers one complete page of PDF File.** Although, I don't need anybody to understand this `template.html` file and any changes made in the above shared HTML code can easily be done in this file ultimately.

```
https://pastebin.com/154ErqUU
```

*pasted the code on pastebin because character limit had exceeded.*

Comment: The attribute `colspan=1` is completely superfluous, since that's the default...

Comment: @Johannes yes, but removing it would make it more complex because this is being taken from Python Script. The value of colspan is coming as argument for every cell and hence, its easier if we keep colspan for every cell (if the value is 2, it makes it colspan = 2, otherwise colspan = 1)

Comment: Upon reviewing the image, I see there are time slots in which there are two different classes commencing at the same time,  hence the use of  `rowspan`. Why are there `rowspan=1` where there is only one class at a particular time slot? For example Friday 8:45am to 10:10am.

Comment: @zer00ne are you talking about colspan? As explained above, it is to make the Python Scripting easier (the value of colspan is being taken as an argument to a `template.html` file through which this HTML Code is being generated. I have however also attached the `template.html` code for clarification.

Comment: No, I understand the reason why `colspan=1` exists, I was in the same situation as you are in now. As a frontend developer I recieved some god aweful tables from the backend so I had to write JavaScript to change the tables when the page loads. Anyways in the image that shows what you trying to accomplish has certain cells stacked on top of each other because there are two classes going on at the same time frame which makes total sense. What doesn't make sense is that some of these stacked cells have a blank, for example Friday 8:45 -10:10am has nothing on top and text below.

Comment: @zer00ne That I believe is a small problem in that Image as well.. Friday 8:45 - 10:10AM should have been one cell only and not two, as shown in the image. 

That image however is not **exactly** what I am trying to achieve, I added that picture only to further elaborate the **two things** I want to achieve (that is, remove the unnecessary padding and second, aligning the Teacher and Room in same row... Below answer helped me with the second problem, but first is still there)

Comment: That should be no problem. Is this table printed on standard paper landscape? Standard landscape oriented would be 279.4mm x 215.9mm. Your table is 297mm x210mm plus if you add margins it'll be a little less but it's close enough in ratio which I assume it is corrected somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the following CSS rulesets:

**Figure I**

| Selector | Property | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `td` | `position` | `relative` |
| `td` | `padding` | `0` |
| `td div` | `position` | `relative` |
| `td p` | `position` | `absolute` |
| `td p` | `margin` | `0` |
| `.course` | `top` | `0.5rem` |
| `.course` | `left` | `0.5rem` |
| `.room` | `bottom` | `0.5rem` |
| `.room` | `right` | `0.5rem` |
| `.teacher` | `bottom` | `0.5rem` |
| `.teacher` | `left` | `0.5rem` |

Basically `<td>` has default padding and `<p>` has default margins so they should zeroed out. All containers are `position: relative` and all content is `position: absolute` and should have a minimum of 2 directions from `left`, `top`, `bottom`, and `right`.

The double stacked cells that should be `rowspan="1"` is too impractical since the rest of the cells would have to be `rowspan="2"` on the `Tuesday` row and then the other rows would be twice the size of a `rowspan="1"` in order to be uniform. Instead there are two `<div>`s stacked within that particular cell (Row 1, Column 3 of `tbody`).

The entire table (with the exception of the borders) are set in `rem`s and are referenced to the `font-size` in `html` (2.85mm = 1rem`). (*See comments in example for details*).

**Figure II**

| Media | Long Side | Length | Width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HTML | width | 278.73mm | 214.89mm |
| Paper | length | 279mm | 216mm |

You can adjust the whole table by changing the `font-size` in `html`, it appears 2.85mm is optimal. Also, the lunch column is reduced signifigantly which gave the rest of the table badly needed space.

There is JavaScript that adds the content, but I wrote it to avoid cluttering the HTML -- it's not a requirement for the solution.

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
const data = [
  {
    row: 0,
    column: 1,
    course: 'Calculus and Analytical Geometry',
    room: 'Room #1',
    teacher: 'Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 0,
    column: 3,
    course: 'Programming Fundamentals',
    room: 'Room #9',
    teacher: 'Dr. Rabia Maqsood',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 0,
    column: 5,
    course: 'Programming Fundamentals - Lab',
    room: 'Lab #1',
    teacher: 'Muhammad Azeem Iftikhar',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 1,
    column: 3,
    course: 'English Composition and Comprehension - Lab',
    room: 'Room #1',
    teacher: 'Rida Akram',
    split: 'A'
  },
  {
    row: 1,
    column: 3,
    course: 'English Composition and Comprehension',
    room: 'Room #7',
    teacher: 'Sadia Ashfaq',
    split: 'B'
  },
  {
    row: 1,
    column: 4,
    course: 'English Composition and Comprehension - Lab',
    room: 'Room #1',
    teacher: 'Rida Akram',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 1,
    column: 5,
    course: 'English Composition and Comprehension',
    room: 'Room #3',
    teacher: 'Farah Iqbal',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 2,
    column: 1,
    course: 'Islamic Studies/Ethics',
    room: 'Room #7',
    teacher: 'Zia Ahmad',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 2,
    column: 3,
    course: 'English Composition and Comprehension',
    room: 'Room #6',
    teacher: 'Sadia Ashfaq',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 2,
    column: 5,
    course: 'Applied Physics',
    room: 'Room #1',
    teacher: 'Waheed Ahmad',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 3,
    column: 2,
    course: 'Calculus and Analytical Geometry',
    room: 'Room #5',
    teacher: 'Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 3,
    column: 3,
    course: 'Programming Fundamentals',
    room: 'Room #10',
    teacher: 'Dr. Rabia Maqsood',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 3,
    column: 4,
    course: 'English Composition and Comprehension',
    room: 'Room #4',
    teacher: 'Farah Iqbal',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 3,
    column: 5,
    course: 'Applied Physics',
    room: 'Room #1',
    teacher: 'Waheed Ahmad',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 4,
    column: 1,
    course: 'Islamic Studies/Ethics',
    room: 'Room #6',
    teacher: 'Zia Ahmad',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 4,
    column: 2,
    course: 'Introduction to Information and Communication Technology - Lab',
    room: 'Lab #4',
    teacher: 'Aqsa Younas',
    split: null
  },
  {
    row: 4,
    column: 3,
    course: 'English Composition and Comprehension - Lab',
    room: 'Room #3',
    teacher: 'Amna Farooq',
    split: null
  },
];

const t = document.querySelector('table').tBodies[0];
const tRows = [...t.rows];

const cellData = (obj) => {
  let r = obj.row;
  let c = obj.column;
  let cell = tRows[r].cells[c];
  if ('split' in obj) {
    let A, B;
    switch (obj.split) {
      case 'A':
        A = cell.querySelector('.A');
        A.children[0].textContent = obj.course;
        A.children[1].textContent = obj.room;
        A.children[2].textContent = obj.teacher;
        break;
      case 'B':
        B = cell.querySelector('.B');
        B.children[0].textContent = obj.course;
        B.children[1].textContent = obj.room;
        B.children[2].textContent = obj.teacher;
        break;
      default:
        cell.children[0].textContent = obj.course;
        cell.children[1].textContent = obj.room;
        cell.children[2].textContent = obj.teacher;
        break;
    }
  }
};

data.forEach((obj) => cellData(obj));
```

```css
/*
✳️ Rulesets pertaining to question
*/ 
:root {
  --thin: 1px solid #777;
  --thick: 3px solid #777;
  --split: 0.5px solid #777;
}

/* 
Global Reference Length
2.85mm = 1rem
Changing the font-size changes all lengths in rem units.
*/
html {
  font: 500 2.85mm/1.5 Georgia;
}

/* 
Letter Size Paper (8.5 x 11in)
216 x 279mm 
75.78 x 97.89rem
816 x 1056px
*/

/* 
Actual Dimensions 1rem = 2.85mm
❉ width: 97.8rem / 278.73mm
✥ height: 75.4rem / 214.89mm
*/
table {
  width: 97.8rem;
  height: 75.4rem;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

caption {
  font-size: 2.4rem; /* ✥ 10.26mm / 3.6rem */
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
}

thead th {
  width: 16.8rem; /* ❉ x 5 */
  height: 3.8rem; /* ✥ */
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-top: var(--thick);
  border-bottom: var(--thick);
  border-right: var(--thin);
}

thead th:first-child {
  width: 9.8rem; /* ❉ */
  border: var(--thick);
}

thead th:last-child {
  border-right: var(--thick);
}

tbody th {
  position: relative;
  border-left: var(--thick);
  border-right: var(--thick);
  border-bottom: var(--thin);
}

tbody > tr:last-child th {
  border-bottom: var(--thick);
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: var(--thick);
}

tbody tr > th:last-child,
tbody tr > td:last-child {
  border-right: var(--thick);
}

td {
  position: relative; /* ✳️ */
  height: 13.6rem;    /* ✥ x 5 */
  padding: 0;         /* ✳️ */
  border: var(--thin);
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td div.A {
  position: relative; /* ✳️ */
  height: 6.8rem;
  border-bottom: var(--split);
}

td div.B {
  position: relative; /* ✳️ */
  height: 6.8rem;
  border-top: var(--split);
}

td p {
  position: absolute; /* ✳️ */
  margin: 0;          /* ✳️ */
}

.course {
  top: 0.5rem;  /* ✳️ */
  left: 0.5rem; /* ✳️ */
}

.room {
  bottom: 0.5rem; /* ✳️ */
  right: 0.5rem;  /* ✳️ */
}

.teacher {
  bottom: 0.5rem; /* ✳️ */
  left: 0.5rem;   /* ✳️ */
}

th.lunch {
  width: 4rem; /* ❉ */
}

td.lunch {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

td.lunch b {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link href="https://website.com/path/to/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style></style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <caption>
        CS-1D
      </caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Day/Period</th>
          <th>I</th>
          <th>II</th>
          <th>III</th>
          <th class="lunch">1:15<br />-<br />1:45</th>
          <th>IV</th>
          <th>V</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Monday</th>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td class="lunch" rowspan="5" colspan="1">
            <b>L<br />U<br />N<br />C<br />H<br /></b>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Tuesday</th>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="A">
              <p class="course"></p>
              <p class="room"></p>
              <p class="teacher"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="B">
              <p class="course"></p>
              <p class="room"></p>
              <p class="teacher"></p>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Wednesday</th>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Thursday</th>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Friday</th>
          <td>
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <p class="course"></p>
            <p class="room"></p>
            <p class="teacher"></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src='https://website.com/path.to/script.js'></script>
    <script></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the 1.

You added a height to every cell, so they are rendered with the height you ask then the text is put in the middle. Remove the `height` on `td` to gain some padding.

Plus, the `rowspan` on "Lunch" is oversized, you have 5 rows (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday) but you set `rowspan="6"`. (The column is going under the others)

For the 2.

The best way to do it: `flex`

Simply put the teacher and the room in the same element, add `display: flex; justify-content: space-between` on it, and they will be on the same line, one on the left, the other on the right.

```css
:root {
  --border-strong: 3px solid #777;
  --border-normal: 1px solid gray;
}

body {
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

table>caption {
  font-size: 6mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 1mm;
}


/* 210 x 297 mm */

table {
  width: 297mm;
  height: 210mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: var(--border-normal);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.6mm;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

tbody tr> :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* top header */

.top_head>th {
  width: 54mm;
  height: 10mm;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-top: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.top_head :first-child {
  width: 27mm;
  border: var(--border-strong);
}

.top_head :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* left header */

tbody th {
  border-left: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody>tr:last-child th {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}


/* row */

tbody td>div {
  height: 34mm;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vertical_span_all {
  font-size: 5mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

.vertical_span_all div {
  height: 10mm;
}


/* td contents */


.note {
  font-size: 3mm;
}

.note :last-child {
  float: right;
}

@page {
  margin: 5mm;
}
.new-page {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
.center
{
  text-align: center;

}
.left
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 6px;
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
/* Remove for 2.
.right
{
    text-align: right;  margin-right: 4px;
}
.teacher
{
    margin-left: 4px;
}
*/
td{
  /* height:175px; removed for 1. */
  width:150px;
}

/* Added for 2. */
.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto 6px;
}

.room {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Heading -->
    <h1 class="center">CS-1D</h1>

<!-- Table -->
    <table border="1">

<!-- Day/Periods -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center" ><br>
                <b>Day/Period</b></br>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>I</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>II</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <b>III</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <b>1:15-1:45</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>IV</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>V</b>
            </td>

        </tr>
<!-- Monday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Monday</b></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Calculus and Analytical Geometry</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #1</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Calculus_and_Analytical_Geometry@Room_#1@Dr.Mushtaq_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>




                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>




                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Dr. Rabia Maqsood</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #9</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals@Room_#9@Dr._Rabia_Maqsood</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td rowspan="5" class="center">
                        <h2>L<br>U<br>N<br>C<br>H</h2>
                    </td>


                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals - Lab</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Muhammad Azeem Iftikhar</span>
                            <span class="room">Lab #1</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals_-_Lab@Lab_#1@Muhammad_Azeem_Iftikhar</p>
                        <p class="right">2</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>






        </tr>
<!-- Tuesday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Tuesday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Rida Akram</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #1</span>
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram<hr>English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#7@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --><p class="left"></p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Sadia Ashfaq</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #7</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram<hr>English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#7@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Rida Akram</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #1</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Farah Iqbal</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #3</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#3@Farah_Iqbal</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>


        </tr>
<!-- Wednesday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Wednesday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Zia Ahmad</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #7</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Islamic_Studies/Ethics@Room_#7@Zia_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Sadia Ashfaq</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #6</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#6@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Applied Physics</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Waheed Ahmad</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #1</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Applied_Physics@Room_#1@Waheed_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>


        </tr>
<!-- Thursday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Thursday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Calculus and Analytical Geometry</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #5</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Calculus_and_Analytical_Geometry@Room_#5@Dr.Mushtaq_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Dr. Rabia Maqsood</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #10</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals@Room_#10@Dr._Rabia_Maqsood</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Farah Iqbal</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #4</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#4@Farah_Iqbal</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Applied Physics</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Waheed Ahmad</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #1</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Applied_Physics@Room_#1@Waheed_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



        </tr>
<!-- Friday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Friday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Zia Ahmad</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #6</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Islamic_Studies/Ethics@Room_#6@Zia_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p class="left">Introduction to Information and Communication Technology - Lab</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Aqsa Younas</span>
                            <span class="room">Lab #4</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Introduction_to_Information_and_Communication_Technology_-_Lab@Lab_#4@Aqsa_Younas</p>
                        <p class="right">2</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>





                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>

                        <p class="info">
                            <span class="teacher">Amna Farooq</span>
                            <span class="room">Room #3</span>
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#3@Amna_Farooq</p>
                        <p class="right">2</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>





        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
<p class = "new-page"></div>


</html>
```

Comment: Removing the height does solve the problem but it also makes the whole page *shrinked*, which is not what I require. I require the page to be, say, according to "printing media" size and hence, the height has to be given for the whole table. When I give that height, it again causes the same problem (unnecessary padding in each cell). For the 2nd, it did solve the issue, thank you!

Comment: As I tried to say yesterday, I removed the table height (which was `210mm`) only to show the change in the preview, you can uncomment it (and I will in my response)

Comment: yup.. Unfortunately though, with the height set at 210mm, the unnecessary padding again comes into play :/

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a little bit. You can see changes in different background cells.

I created

```
<div class="cell">
  <div class="class">
    <div class="class__name">
       <p>Class Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="class__information">
       <p>Teacher Name</p>
       <p>Room Name</p>
    </div>
 </div>
 <hr>
 <div class="class">ADD ANOTHER CLASS IF YOU HAVE LIKE IN TUESDAY III </div>
</div>
```

---

Found out margin problem happens because of margins in content in my solution **p** tags create margin so for that solve the problem

```
.cell p {
  margin:0;
}
```

---

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

:root {
  --border-strong: 3px solid #777;
  --border-normal: 1px solid gray;
}

.cell p{
  margin: 0;
}

.cell hr{
  margin: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
} 

body {
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

table>caption {
  font-size: 6mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 1mm;
}


/* 210 x 297 mm */

table {
  width: 297mm;
  height: 210mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: var(--border-normal);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.6mm;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

tbody tr> :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* top header */

.top_head>th {
  width: 54mm;
  height: 10mm;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-top: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.top_head :first-child {
  width: 27mm;
  border: var(--border-strong);
}

.top_head :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* left header */

tbody th {
  border-left: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody>tr:last-child th {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}


/* row */

tbody td>div {
  height: 34mm;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vertical_span_all {
  font-size: 5mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

.vertical_span_all div {
  height: 10mm;
}

.note {
  font-size: 3mm;
}

.note :last-child {
  float: right;
}

@page {
  margin: 5mm;
}
.new-page {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
.center
{
  text-align: center;

}

td{
  height:175px;
  width:150px;
}


.cell{
 height: 100%; 
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.class{
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 0 0.1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: bisque;
  
}

.class__information{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
 <h1 class="center">CS-1D</h1>

    <!-- Table -->
        <table border="1">
    
    <!-- Day/Periods -->
            <tr>
                <td class="center" ><br>
                    <b>Day/Period</b></br>
                </td>
                <td class="center" >
                    <b>I</b>
                </td>
                <td class="center" >
                    <b>II</b>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <b>III</b>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <b>1:15-1:45</b>
                </td>
                <td class="center" >
                    <b>IV</b>
                </td>
                <td class="center" >
                    <b>V</b>
                </td>
    
            </tr>
    <!-- Monday -->
            <tr>
                <td class="center">
                    <b>Monday</b></td>
                <td colspan=1>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <div class="class">
                            <div class="class__name">
                                <p>Calculus and Analytical Geometry</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="class__information">
                                <p>Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad</p>
                                <p>Room #1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan=1></td>
                <td colspan=1>
                   <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals</p>
                   <p class = "right">Room #9</p>
                    <p class = "teacher">Dr. Rabia Maqsood</p>
                <td rowspan="6" class="center">
                     <h2>L<br>U<br>N<br>C<br>H</h2>
                </td>
    
    
                        <td colspan=2>
                            <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals - Lab</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Lab #1</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Muhammad Azeem Iftikhar</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals_-_Lab@Lab_#1@Muhammad_Azeem_Iftikhar</p>
                            <p class="right">2</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
    
    
    
            </tr>
    <!-- Tuesday -->
            <tr>
                <td class="center">
                    <b>Tuesday</b>
                </td>
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            </td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            </td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <div class="cell">
                                <div class="class">
                                    <div class="class__name">
                                        <p>English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="class__information">
                                        <p>Rida Akram</p>
                                        <p>Room #1</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="class">
                                    <div class="class__name">
                                        <p>English Composition and Comprehension</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="class__information">
                                        <p>Sadia Ashfaq</p>
                                        <p>Room #7</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           </td> 
                            
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #1</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Rida Akram</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #3</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Farah Iqbal</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#3@Farah_Iqbal</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
            </tr>
    <!-- Wednesday -->
            <tr>
                <td class="center">
                    <b>Wednesday</b>
                </td>
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #7</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Zia Ahmad</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">Islamic_Studies/Ethics@Room_#7@Zia_Ahmad</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            </td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #6</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Sadia Ashfaq</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#6@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            </td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">Applied Physics</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #1</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Waheed Ahmad</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">Applied_Physics@Room_#1@Waheed_Ahmad</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
            </tr>
    <!-- Thursday -->
            <tr>
                <td class="center">
                    <b>Thursday</b>
                </td>
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            </td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">Calculus and Analytical Geometry</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #5</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">Calculus_and_Analytical_Geometry@Room_#5@Dr.Mushtaq_Ahmad</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #10</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Dr. Rabia Maqsood</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals@Room_#10@Dr._Rabia_Maqsood</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #4</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Farah Iqbal</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#4@Farah_Iqbal</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">Applied Physics</p>
    
                            <p class = "right">Room #1</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Waheed Ahmad</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">Applied_Physics@Room_#1@Waheed_Ahmad</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
            </tr>
    <!-- Friday -->
            <tr>
                <td class="center">
                    <b>Friday</b>
                </td>
    
    
                        <td colspan=1>
                            <p class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #6</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Zia Ahmad</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">Islamic_Studies/Ethics@Room_#6@Zia_Ahmad</p>
                            <p class="right">1</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=2>
                            <p class="left">Introduction to Information and Communication Technology - Lab</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Lab #4</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Aqsa Younas</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">Introduction_to_Information_and_Communication_Technology_-_Lab@Lab_#4@Aqsa_Younas</p>
                            <p class="right">2</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
    
    
                        <td colspan=2>
                            <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>
    
                                        <p class = "right">Room #3</p>
    
                            <p class = "teacher">Amna Farooq</p>
                            <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#3@Amna_Farooq</p>
                            <p class="right">2</p>
                            <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>
    
    
    
    
    
            </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: That's a very good answer, but unfortunately it is something that doesn't work. I don't have the luxury of adding the class for the "line"... The line is being added through <hr> which is coming in the string I am sending from the Python Script.

Comment: I found a way for you to get rid of `.line` edited in the code. @AwaisShahid

Answer (score 1):

Remove Height from the **table, td,**, and **div** all unnecessary height cause issues.

```css
:root {
  --border-strong: 3px solid #777;
  --border-normal: 1px solid gray;
}

body {
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

table>caption {
  font-size: 6mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 1mm;
}


/* 210 x 297 mm */

table {
  width: 297mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: var(--border-normal);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.6mm;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

tbody tr> :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* top header */

.top_head>th {
  width: 54mm;
  height: 10mm;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-top: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.top_head :first-child {
  width: 27mm;
  border: var(--border-strong);
}

.top_head :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* left header */

tbody th {
  border-left: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody>tr:last-child th {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}


/* row */

tbody td>div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vertical_span_all {
  font-size: 5mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

.vertical_span_all div {
}


/* td contents */


.note {
  font-size: 3mm;
}

.note :last-child {
  float: right;
}

@page {
  margin: 5mm;
}
.new-page {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
.center
{
  text-align: center;

}
.left
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 6px;
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
.right
{
    text-align: right;  margin-right: 4px;
}
.teacher
{
    margin-left: 4px;
}
td{
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Heading -->
    <h1 class="center">CS-1D</h1>

<!-- Table -->
    <table border="1">

<!-- Day/Periods -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center" ><br>
                <b>Day/Period</b></br>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>I</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>II</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <b>III</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <b>1:15-1:45</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>IV</b>
            </td>
            <td class="center" >
                <b>V</b>
            </td>

        </tr>
<!-- Monday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Monday</b></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Calculus and Analytical Geometry</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Calculus_and_Analytical_Geometry@Room_#1@Dr.Mushtaq_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>




                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>




                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #9</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Dr. Rabia Maqsood</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals@Room_#9@Dr._Rabia_Maqsood</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td rowspan="6" class="center">
                        <h2>L<br>U<br>N<br>C<br>H</h2>
                    </td>


                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Lab #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Muhammad Azeem Iftikhar</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals_-_Lab@Lab_#1@Muhammad_Azeem_Iftikhar</p>
                        <p class="right">2</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>






        </tr>
<!-- Tuesday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Tuesday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Rida Akram<hr>English Composition and Comprehension</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram<hr>English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#7@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --><p class="left"></p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #7</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Sadia Ashfaq</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram<hr>English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#7@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Rida Akram</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#1@Rida_Akram</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #3</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Farah Iqbal</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#3@Farah_Iqbal</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>


        </tr>
<!-- Wednesday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Wednesday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #7</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Zia Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Islamic_Studies/Ethics@Room_#7@Zia_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #6</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Sadia Ashfaq</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#6@Sadia_Ashfaq</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Applied Physics</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Waheed Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Applied_Physics@Room_#1@Waheed_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>


        </tr>
<!-- Thursday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Thursday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        </td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Calculus and Analytical Geometry</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #5</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Dr.Mushtaq Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Calculus_and_Analytical_Geometry@Room_#5@Dr.Mushtaq_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Programming Fundamentals</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #10</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Dr. Rabia Maqsood</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Programming_Fundamentals@Room_#10@Dr._Rabia_Maqsood</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #4</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Farah Iqbal</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension@Room_#4@Farah_Iqbal</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Applied Physics</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #1</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Waheed Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Applied_Physics@Room_#1@Waheed_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



        </tr>
<!-- Friday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Friday</b>
            </td>


                    <td colspan=1>
                        <p class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #6</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Zia Ahmad</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Islamic_Studies/Ethics@Room_#6@Zia_Ahmad</p>
                        <p class="right">1</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>



                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p class="left">Introduction to Information and Communication Technology - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Lab #4</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Aqsa Younas</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">Introduction_to_Information_and_Communication_Technology_-_Lab@Lab_#4@Aqsa_Younas</p>
                        <p class="right">2</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>





                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</p>

                                    <p class = "right">Room #3</p>

                        <p class = "teacher">Amna Farooq</p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">English_Composition_and_Comprehension_-_Lab@Room_#3@Amna_Farooq</p>
                        <p class="right">2</p>
                        <p class="teacher"></p> --></td>





        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
<p class = "new-page"></div>


</html>
```

Comment: That fixes the problem, but the problem is still the same, the resultant page is not big enough to be printed on "print media", the table covers up only half of the page.

Comment: have you tried height 100% or 100vh? Maybe it will help..

Comment: Where would I put 100vh or height 100%? I tried to put it in table CSS but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

add the following css:

```
table {
    height: unset!important;
    width: unset!important;
}
td {
    height: unset!important;
}
```

Edit:

### Explanation

the padding is caused by the height & width of the elements once you make them unset you remove the padding and the !important is just to make it compulsory